# An induction problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Recently I started to learn some induction problems, and I'm stuck with this one:

prove that, for each $n$ $\in \mathbb N$, $(n-1)^2$ divides $n^n - n^2 + n - 1$.

There are no tips or answers in the textbook on how to solve this problem, so I'm little bit stuck and frustrated. Here's what I got:

Basis: $n = 1$, $(1-1)^2 = 0$, and for $n = 1$ we have $1^1 - 1^2 + 1 - 1 = 0$, so for $n = 1$ it's true.

Induction Hypothesis: for each $n$ $\in \mathbb N$, $(n-1)^2$ divides $n^n - n^2 + n - 1$.

Induction Step:  this is where I'm stuck. I know that I must show that for $((n+1)-1)^2$ = $n^2$, the number $({n^2})^{n^2} - n^2 + n - 1$ is equal to zero.

So, is there anyone who can help me, or give any advice? Thank you in advance.

Comment: YOu don't have to show it is equal to $0$.  You have to show that $n^2$ divides evenly into $(n+1)^(n+1) - (n+1)^2 + (n+1) -1$.

Comment: ok, I get it. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the inductive step, you must show that $n^2$ divides

$(n+1)^{n+1}-(n+1)^2+n$.

From the binomial expansion, that is equivalent to $n^2$ dividing $1+n(n+1)-(n+1)^2+n$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: ok, I understand everything. After a while I noticed where I was wrong. Good lesson. Thank you.